# Type '() => number' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings

I'm trying to do something very simple:

```
DateToString(date: Date): string {
       let month: number = date.getMonth;
       let day: number = date.getDate;
       let year: number = date.getFullYear;

       return (month + 1) + '/' + day + '/' + year;
   }
```

However I get the error from the title 
"Type '() => number' is not assignable to type 'number'". 
If instead I try to make the type '() => number' instead of 'number', that error goes away and I get the error 
"Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '() => number' and 'number'".

Using Vue and class-based-decorators with Typescript.
Any ideas?

Comment: `getMonth`, `getDate`, and `getFullYear` are functions. To _invoke_ those functions you need to have parentheses after them e.g. `getMonth()`. If you _do not_ include the parentheses you get a reference to the function itself.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Thanks so much! I can't believe that caused so much wasted time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getMonth`, etc., have to be called as functions.

```
DateToString(date: Date): string {
       let month: number = date.getMonth();
       let day: number = date.getDate();
       let year: number = date.getFullYear();

       return (month + 1) + '/' + day + '/' + year;
   }
```

By the way, there's already a function `toLocaleDateString()` that will do what you want to do above, although it gives different results depending on the client system's locale settings -- which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help!